# Windows Azure- Update and Add resource files

Tags: azure, globalization

I am new to the Windows Azure world, and I have some doubts about the use of resource files in an deployed application.

When I have a application deployed, is it possible to add or update existing Resource (resx) files without rebuilding the application? I have already read some information but I am not sure yet of the best practices for this situation.

I have seen suggestions of inserting the content of resource files in the Table or blob storage, but also that the update of the files would not force the rebuild, as long as the application pool is "recycled".

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to confirm, you do refer to Windows Azure Web Role and not to Windows Azure Website?

Comment: Yes, I am refering to Web Roles. However, we decided to solve this problem in a different way, inserting the data in the database instead of resource files.

Comment: Each solution has it pros and cons and before making any decisions it would be good for you to review most of them. Having resource files is very convenient from development point of view. But then any change (even small typo) will have to result in new code build (and QA process; but that depends on your company rules). Having resources in database allows you to split *content* from *logic*. We did similar change (move content from resources to a database) for one of ours Azure applications and it was very good change for us. Good luck with your change!

Comment: Thanks Tom. At the moment we think this is the best solution, for the flexibilty it provides, in the case of corrections to Translations or addition of new Languages.

Answer (score 0):

I've just thought same thing like you want  when I want to change something on our code I have to redeploy our app to Azure and it takes a long time to upload but I don't know Is it possible to update your Resource (resx) files.

I found some solution about this situation on Steve Marx's blog  who is Chief Windows Azure Architect :[Update Your Windows Azure Website in Just Seconds by Syncing with Blob Storage](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/update-your-windows-azure-website-in-just-seconds-by-syncing-with-blob-storage)

It is a pretty good solution and If you apply this way , you can save your time of during your deployment process .

Comment: It sounds like a good solution indeed, but I am not sure if the application applies the updates in the resource files. Anyway, we decided to solve this problem in a different way, inserting the data in the database instead of resource files.